# Cordova Visual Studio Building Bug

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I would like to create App for Windows Phone Store but when I try build app in Visual Studio 2015, I get a lot of errors. My Cordova version is 4.1.0

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   TS6053  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/lib/ngCordova/LICENSE.ts' not found.  CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
Error   TS6053  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/lib/angular-ui-router/LICENSE.ts' not found.  CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
Error   TS6054  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/cordova.js' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'. CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
Error   TS6054  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/css/.DS_Store' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'.  CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
Error   TS6054  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/cordova_plugins.js' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'. CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
Error   TS6054  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/img/.DS_Store' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'.  CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
Error   TS6054  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/css/style.css' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'.  CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
Error   TS6054  Build: File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/App/platforms/windows/www/img/01.jpg' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'. CordovaApp.Phone    C:\Users\admin\Desktop\App\platforms\windows\VSTSC  1
```

Initially, the application was developed on MacOS with the same version of Cordova. Now my system is Windows 10.
What do I need to do to be able to build an application for Windows Phone?

I tried on another project, an older version of Cordova and everything works. It is going somehow solve this problem on newer versions of Cordova?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I'm having it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After update Cordova to 6.0 everything works on Windows 10.

Comment: I have the same problem with Cordova 6 :(

Comment: Did you try build new blank project  ?